# How to efficiently check if items in array A exist in array B?

Tags: solidity, arrays

I need to compare 2 uint256[]'s checking if the items in one array exist in the second array. Would love declare a `mapping (uint256 => bool) exists` within the function and loop through the second array assigning true to the items, and loop through the second array checking if the items exist — but it's not possible to declare mappings to memory.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of ints you are going to have on both arrays and the maximum value of those ints?
For example, do you know if both arrays will have a maximum of 100 elements each and that the maximum int value will be 20? Or they can have any number of elements of any size?

Comment: @JeremyThen unknown maximum for both

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this source that explains the two approaches: (1) using view functions to loop through an array and return true if item exists with O(n) complexity or (2) duplicate the value as keys of a mapping that can be accessed directly through its key with O(1) complexity.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226909/how-to-check-if-one-value-exists-in-an-array

Comment: Thought of that, but I would also need to clear the mapping for it to work — would be 3 for loops in total, where 2 make write calls to storage